# How to fix" ERROR: Failed building wheel for fa2"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, setup.py

I'm trying to install fa2 package for plotting network.I have to write "pip install fa2" in Anaconda Prompt, but I get the error "failed building wheel for fa2". I don't know what it means or how to solve this, can anyone help me?

Win 64, Python 3.6.9

It shows as follows:

```
(base) C:\Users\To find Berlin>pip install fa2
Collecting fa2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/d1/aa67d917628d29b83f3413790155da575865f3eab8b6e577c5871ef987d8/fa2-0.3.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in i:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from fa2) (1.16.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in i:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from fa2) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in i:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from fa2) (4.36.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: fa2
  Building wheel for fa2 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'I:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TOFIND~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1ah38ucg\\fa2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TOFIND~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1ah38ucg\\fa2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\TOFIND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-w1fjglo3' --python-tag cp36
       cwd: C:\Users\TOFIND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ah38ucg\fa2\
  Complete output (30 lines):
  Installing fa2 package (fastest forceatlas2 python implementation)

  >>>> Cython is installed?
  Yes

  >>>> Starting to install!

  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
  copying fa2\fa2util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
  copying fa2\forceatlas2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
  copying fa2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
  running egg_info
  writing fa2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to fa2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to fa2.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to fa2.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'fa2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'fa2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying fa2\fa2util.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
  copying fa2\fa2util.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
  running build_ext
  skipping 'fa2\fa2util.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
  building 'fa2.fa2util' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fa2
  Running setup.py clean for fa2
Failed to build fa2
Installing collected packages: fa2
    Running setup.py install for fa2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'I:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TOFIND~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1ah38ucg\\fa2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TOFIND~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1ah38ucg\\fa2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\TOFIND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9fbzhyxp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\TOFIND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1ah38ucg\fa2\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    Installing fa2 package (fastest forceatlas2 python implementation)

    >>>> Cython is installed?
    Yes

    >>>> Starting to install!

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
    copying fa2\fa2util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
    copying fa2\forceatlas2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
    copying fa2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
    running egg_info
    writing fa2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to fa2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to fa2.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to fa2.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'fa2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'fa2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying fa2\fa2util.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
    copying fa2\fa2util.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\fa2
    running build_ext
    skipping 'fa2\fa2util.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'fa2.fa2util' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'I:\Anaconda\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TOFIND~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1ah38ucg\\fa2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\TOFIND~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1ah38ucg\\fa2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\TOFIND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9fbzhyxp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Then I want to install fa2 by

```
python setup.py install
```

It shows:

```
(base) C:\Users\To find Berlin>python setup.py install
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The message tells you what is wrong and what to do about it: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ 
The issue is that pip can't find a 64-bit Windows binary so it is trying to build one from source. On Windows this is not straightforward, and to start with you need the right C compiler.

Comment: Thank you, I'm downloading it now, and try to see if it will works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required